# correlation operation written using the convolution operator: h(-w) * R(w)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convolution

Below is a convolution integral.
$$\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(\alpha)~R_{XY}(\tau+\alpha)~d\alpha = h(-\tau) * R_{XY}(\tau)$$

But, How did they get the minus sign in $h(-\tau)$, as in $h(-\tau) * R_{XY}(\tau)$?

I thought for the convolution operator, it was a  requirement that the parameter to the function on the left side and right side are the same?  which is why they write $(f*g)(t) = f(t)*g(t)$... but here we have $f(-t) * g(t)$ ... is this right?

does:

$f(t) \star g(t) = f(-t) * g(t)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are equivalent. Assuming $\star$ for correlation and * for convolution.

$f(t) \star g(t) = \int_{-\inf}^{\inf} f(\tau) g(\tau + t) d\tau$

Let $\alpha = -\tau$ so $d\tau = -d\alpha$:

$= \int_{\inf}^{-\inf} f(-\alpha) g(- \alpha + t) (- d\alpha )$

$= - \int_{\inf}^{-\inf} f(-\alpha) g(- \alpha + t) d\alpha$

$= \int_{-\inf}^{\inf} f(-\alpha) g(t - \alpha) d\alpha$

$= f(-t) * g(t)$

Comment: thanks.  makes sense....how would you prove it the other way around: $f(t) \star g(t) = f(-t) * g(t)$?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by other way around, as you wrote the same equation I wrote. If you mean that $f(t) * g(t) = f(-t) \star g(t)$, that would be a nearly identical. Start with the definition of convolution, change variable being integrated over to be negative, and flip the bounds, and you should get the definition for $f(-t) \star g(t)$. Just make sure not to mix up the notation as people will use stuff like $f(t + a) \star g(t)$ or $f(-t) * g(t)$, to mean modifying $f$ before/within the correlation or convolution

Comment: $$\begin{aligned}f(t) \star g(t) = f(-t) * g(t) \\f(-t) * g(t) = f(t) \star g(t)\end{aligned}$$ let $w(t) = f(-t) ~~~\Longrightarrow~~~w(-t)=f(t)$ $$\boxed{w(t) * g(t) = w(-t) \star g(t)}$$